# Google's Review Snippet in SERPs - Is it available for the Service schema type?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I am working on some projects for small service based businesses that offer not physical products but actual services. Think service based industries like roofers, plumbers, etc.

I am starting to plan out a much deeper deployment for the Schema I build into their service pages, but I am now wondering if there is a rhyme or reason to why certain plugins like PulseM for example use the Product schema type instead of Service schema type.

My plan is to collect reviews after completion of the service from the end users that can be featured on the website. Unique to the specific area and service offered and then build aggregateRating off of them. Not pulling them in from external buckets of reviews as that appears to be against guidelines.

So for instance "Detroit Furnace Maintenance" would be the Service being offered and it would feature reviews in a slider on the page and schema representing it.

Will that be eligible as for rich snippets or no?

The reason I ask before getting started is it's kind of unclear on their documentation:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet

Service is not listed in the list of available Schema types it is available for, but the bulleted item below mentions it:

- Refer clearly to a specific product or service by nesting the review
  within the markup of another schema.org type, such as schema.org/Book
  or schema.org/Recipe, or by using a schema.org type as a value for

It does appear that aggregateRating is available for use on Service schema:
https://schema.org/Service

Any input on this or experience with it working out or not on a "Service" would be great.